# Angular 1.5 : Not able to initialize the correct Select item

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build the select item component using angular js. But it is not selecting the correct default selected value.

I am initializing the select item value as `{"brandSetCode":1,"bannerColor":null,"fontColor":null};`

But it always selects the last element. How to solve this issue?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="sanitizeExample">
       <script>
         angular.module('sanitizeExample', ['ngSanitize'])
           .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope, $sce) {
             $scope.initSelectItem ={"brandSetCode":null,"bannerColor":null,"fontColor":null};
             
             $scope.mySelectableItems =[{
 "label": "All",
 "value": {
  "brandSetCode": null,
  "bannerColor": null,
  "fontColor": null
 }
}, {
 "label": "SPIRITS",
 "value": {
  "brandSetCode": 1,
  "bannerColor": null,
  "fontColor": null
 }
},
 {
"label": "WINES",
"value": {
 "brandSetCode": 3,
 "bannerColor": null,
 "fontColor": null
}
}
];
             
           }]);
           
          
     </script>
     <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <select name="brand"
       data-ng-model="initSelectItem"
      data-ng-options="brand.value as brand.label for brand in mySelectableItems track by $index">
    </select> 
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-init()` and initialize the default option.

```
<select ng-init="initSelectItemDefault()" ng-model="initSelectItem" ng-options="brand.label for brand in mySelectableItems">
  </select>
```

And in controller

```
 $scope.initSelectItemDefault = function(){
    $scope.initSelectItem = $scope.mySelectableItems.filter(e => e.label == "All")[0];
  }
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/yvYGoynSxrwdSeFqiTKM?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `track by` or manually compare them because track by adds a field named $$hash in the model.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="sanitizeExample">
       <script>
         angular.module('sanitizeExample', ['ngSanitize'])
           .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope, $sce) {
             $scope.initSelectItem = {};
             
             $scope.mySelectableItems =[{
 "label": "All",
 "value": {
  "brandSetCode": -1,
  "bannerColor": -1,
  "fontColor": -1
 }
}, {
 "label": "SPIRITS",
 "value": {
  "brandSetCode": 1,
  "bannerColor": null,
  "fontColor": null
 }
}
];
             
           }]);
           
          
     </script>
     <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <select name="brand" ng-init="initSelectItem = mySelectableItems[0].value"
       data-ng-model="initSelectItem"
      data-ng-options="brand.value as brand.label for brand in mySelectableItems">
             
    </select> 
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```